# Why does Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 complain about Undefined Functions on my computer but not others?

Tags: ms-access, oledb, jet

As a preface, **please note that this posting is NOT a duplicate** question about any of the following common issues with `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0`:

- This is NOT the "There is no 64-bit version of `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0`"-problem.

  - I am running a 32-bit .NET executable on both machines.
  - Both machines have the 32-bit version of Office 2019 (via Office 365) installed.
- This is also NOT the "Using Access/VBA functions inside JET" problem.

  - Functions like `Nz()` are only available inside SQL executed inside Access VBA, those functions are not available inside SQL executed through the JET or ACE.
  - However `CLng` **is** a JET intrinsic function that should work when used through JET (i.e. outside of Access VBA).

---

#### Problem statement:

- I have a SQL query that uses a JET intrinsic function such as `CLng()`. Below is a minimal query that reproduces the problem:

  ```
  SELECT
      CLNG( 123 ) AS Foo
  ```
- When I run this query on my computer (with 32-bit Office 2019 via Office 365 installed):

  - When I use the `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` OLE-DB provider it fails with this exception message:

    > `OleDbException` Undefined function 'CLNG' in expression.
    > `HResult: -2147217900`
    > `NativeError: -530123806`
    > `SQLState: 3085`
  - When I use the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0` OLE-DB provider it succeeds.
- When I run this query on another computer (also with 32-bit Office 2019 via Office 365 installed):

  - When I use the `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` OLE-DB provider it succeeds.
  - When I use the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0` OLE-DB provider it succeeds.
- The same database file is used in both computers, it's a JET 4.0 (Access 2000) `*.mdb` database file.

Both computers report the same information for the JET and ACE drivers when enumerating 32-bit OLE-DB providers (see screenshot below, my computer is on top, the other computer is at the bottom):

[image]

- I am not testing with `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` because ACE 15 (Office 2013) and ACE 16 (Office 2016, Office 2019) both overwrite the ACE 12 provider registration so that any application requesting ACE 12 will get ACE 15 or 16 instead.

---

#### Assumptions:

I'm going to assume there's some flag or systemwide switch that configures how `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` handles intrinsic functions (I understand that the JET 4.0 driver can run in SQL-89 and SQL-92 modes, I wonder if it's related to that) which doesn't affect the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0` driver.

I'll be reaching out to Office support over this incident and report back their answer - if any, but if anyone has any idea I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting.
Have you checked the sandbox settings for JET/ACE?

The sandbox settings will prevent use of "some" functions in JET/ACE sql, and prevent (not allow) them to be used.

info here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/office/turn-sandbox-mode-on-or-off-to-disable-macros-8cc7bad8-38c2-4a7a-a604-43e9a7bbc4fb

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/office/functions-and-properties-in-access-blocked-by-sandbox-mode-9a829783-f7a8-4a9f-8d43-8650b8cc9565?ui=en-us&rs=en-ie&ad=ie

However, clng() is NOT one of the blocked sql functions. So I do doubt this would be a issue. But, I would do a quick test/check of these issue. (again, my sorry for suggesting a long shot - based on your given information, this should not be your issue).

Right now, best guess? You want to install a JET sp update on your dev box that fails.
I would try sp8 from here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7151

Your writeup seems VERY through. And since queries DO WORK, just not those with some functions. I HAVE seen this issue in the past - and I can't remember the solution. I recall this was around 2003!. We found that "some" functions in sql would work, and some don't. I seem to recall the fix was to re-register a extra .dll that provides jet with SOME additional functions native to jet. In other words there is a .dll that holds/adds/allows some of the JET sql functions. if that part is broken, then SOME jet functions don't work.

Question:
do other JET native functions fail? Or all of them?
If all fail, I would look at sandbox settings. And if some,then sp8 install is a best guess.

And give that this is 100% jet, then issues such as broken references IN regards to VBA does not apply here. And I recall this was NOT VBA functions failing and it was NOT due to broken VBA references. (once they go south, then near all of the sql() functions can break WHEN using Access applications, including JET sql.. (again: you using JET, not really access).

I suppose the other long shot? If this is a different  mdb, or a copy that you been beating to death during testing? I would consider launching it with access and do a compact + repair.

The all or just "some" jet sql functions would shed light on this. However, once you find this answer, I don't have a solution! But if ALL functions() fail no matter what? Well, then JET as opposed to ACE is borked on that machine. You need to re-install JET. I not done that since about 2007. (JET is part of windows).

I don't think you can/will find JET for download. But you can google for JET sp packs - so that is my best shot and advice - try installing a JET sp8 pack.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that on my machine I had earlier done a *forced install* of the 64-bit ACE driver when the 32-bit ACE driver was already installed. After uninstalling the 64-bit ACE driver (and re-installing the 32-bit ACE driver for good-measure) it started working as-expected again.

---

I **suspect** that the 32-bit and 64-bit ACE drivers always delegates JET's built-ins (that aren't in the ODBC-compatible subset) to the Visual Basic runtime DLL which needs to be 32-bit or 64-bit compatible with the ACE driver, but it tries to load it in a way that fails when the 32-bit/64-bit ISA is incorrect (which is trivial to do correctly, I should probably use a tool like `ProcMon` to see what's really going on...).